# When Bob was same age as Brooke, Phil was $20$. And when Brooke was same age as Phill, Bob was $14$. How old is Brooke now?

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

> When Bob was same age as Brooke, Phil was $20$. And when Brooke was same age as Phill, Bob was $14$. How old is Brooke now?

Even if that's a question, your tips are more important for me. Honestly, I'm afraid of these questions that seem complex. As I mean, what do we have to do when we're solving the age word problems? So, am trying to find a method that is useful, easy, not complex. As seen, I've no idea about the question.

With my kindest regards!

Comment: Give names to the quantities you don't know, and relate them numerically with the given information. In this particular case, they all seem to be related with addition and/or subtraction. How about you give it a shot.

Comment: @rschwieb what do you mean? Can you be more clear?

Comment: Nope. Not possible.

Comment: @rschwieb am just looking for a strategy to solve age word problems better because it seems too complex right now. that's why I'm trying to learn a strategy to make it easier.

Comment: memorizing methods/strategies for solving similar questions is the worst way to study math.

Comment: Indeed, I'm not memorizing methods/strategies, just trying to get what the question wants from us.

Comment: @Busi I just described the strategy in its simplest, most applicable form.  what are you having trouble with so far... assigning symbols for the quantities you don't know? Update me on your progress and I can say more.

Comment: @rschwieb No, sir. You didn't. You just told me that I need to relate them numerically with given information. and no clue about you want me to make an equation or something.

Comment: @Busi well, you shouldn't even be thinking about that part until you've settled the first half of the advice... have you?

Comment: @rschwieb I really didn't get what you mean :/

Comment: @Busi How are you going to solve *any* problem if you don't know what you're looking for? You have give the quantities in a problem names, so that you can proceed to relate them algebraically.

Comment: @rschwieb That's what I need help with. If you actually want me to show attempt, let's call them as $B$, $B'$ and $P$. $a$ years from now, $B = B'$ and $P = 20$, also $B' = P$, $B = 14$ it asks us to find out $B'$. you see where I'm failing.

Comment: @Busi The system is underspecified, as far as I can tell. From the outset you have more unknowns than equations. While one can work out that phil is 17, it turns out that you can pick any age for Bob and make Brooke 3 years older, and that solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with such questions, the method is basically always the same : state that $x = $ *something*, $y=$ *something*, ect...Then, translate the sentences from English to maths.

Here : $x=$ age of Bob, $y=$ age of Brooke, $z=$ age of Phil.

> When Bob was the same age of Brooke, Phil was $20$.

This translates into  : $z = 20 + (x-y)$. Indeed, Bob was the same age than Brooke $x-y$ years ago.

Now it's your turn ; how would you translate :

> When Brooke was same age as Phill, Bob was 14.

Once you figured it out, hopefully you'll be able to work out the solution.

Comment: So, will I use $x-y$ for Bob while writng it down? And once I figured it out, can you tell what I'm going to do?

Comment: Not quite. Why did I use $x-y$ ? Because $x-(x-y) = y$, which means, in  English : *$x-y$ years ago, Bob was the same age than the current age of Brooke*. Now the reasonning is the same for the second sentence, but $x-y$ won't do it.

Comment: Got it. Can you tell what I'm going to do after figuring the next equation out?

Comment: Well, you need to solve the equations simultaneously, of course :]

Answer (score 0):

A *big* difficulty here is that the problem tricks you into using the same name for different quantities.  "Phil's age at the time when Bob had the age that Brooke does now" is *not* the same as "Phil's age at the time when *Phil* had the age that Brooke does now" (which is just Brooke's age).

I'm going to use krirkrirk's notation, slightly clarified:
$$x = \text{Bob's age now,}\quad y = \text{Brooke's age now,}
\quad z = \text{Phil's age now.}$$

So let's translate your first assumption into an equation:

"When Bob has the age that Brooke has now…" …when is that exactly? It's not now — we can't assume $x=y$. Rather, we're looking at a time $a$ years in the future (or $-a$ years in the past), when Bob's age will be $x+a$; and our condition becomes (1) $x+a=y$.

"…Phil is 20".  Note that this is the time $a$ years in the future (or $-a$ in the past), when Phil's age will be (or was) $z+a$.  And we're now being told that that age is 20, so: (2) $z+a=20$.

At this point, we can eliminate $a$ as a variable (we don't really care *when* this is happening, so we don't need $a$ around).  We can do this by solving for $a$ in (1) and substituting into (2), or vice versa, or by taking the difference of the two equations.  Doing the last, we get $\boxed{x - z = y - 20}$ (the other procedures will yield an equivalent condition).

(Note that we could wait to do this, but then we'd be dealing with more equations in more unknowns.)

**Exercise:** Translate the second condition to a similar equation.

Now we have two equations to deal with in three unknowns, which you may have been told is bad. And it is, if we need to know exactly what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are.  But we don't; we only care about the value of $y$.  And if you did the exercise correctly, you should be able to eliminate $x-z$ the same way we eliminated $a$, and end up with a single solvable equation in $y$.

Comment: Maybe you should try it all the way to the end. As far as I can see, $(x,y,z,a,b)=(x,x+3, 17, 3, 14-x)$ is a solution to the systems you're suggesting for any $x$. it looks like you can determine Phil's age uniquely, but not Brooke's. Could have made a typo somewhere I suppose *shrug*.

Comment: @rschweib I'm fairly sure the error is on your end.

Comment: Well, hear me out before you dismiss me. I didn’t say anyone had made an error. I can’t say either way because you left half your equations out. Do you disagree for example that $(x,y,z)=(1,4,17)$ and $(x,y,z)=(2,5,17)$ both work?

Comment: The other equation I get is $x-z=14-y$, leading to $y=17$. Are you sure you don't have $y$ and $z$ switched? (I left the second equation out initially so as not to give the whole solution away.)

Comment: Shifting Brooke's age to Phil's by doing $y+b=z$ would mean $x+b=14$. That would yield $x-y=14-z$ instead of what you wrote.  I mean, if you agree that the two things I gave above satisfy the description in the original word problem, then there can be no doubt.

Comment: Oh shoot, you're right, the problem as printed is somewhere between super-ambiguous and nonsensical. Since my reading is the only one that gives an definite answer, I'm sticking with it, but it's a pretty bad problem. I'm sorry for being so dismissive earlier.

Comment: There are a lot of bad smells. It expects a solution that isn’t possible, it suggests bob is older than Brooke when that is not possible. It is apparently just a poorly constructed problem.